# How can i detect my digital camera connected to my pc usb ? Also the camera name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of form1:

```
class USBDeviceInfo
        {
            public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
            {
                this.DeviceID = deviceID;
                this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
                this.Description = description;
            }
            public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
            public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
            public string Description { get; private set; }
        }
```

And

```
List<string> cameras = new List<string>();
```

In constructor:

```
var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();
                foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
                {
                    cameras.Add(usbDevice.DeviceID);
                    cameras.Add(usbDevice.PnpDeviceID);
                    cameras.Add(usbDevice.Description);
                }
```

The GetUSBDevices() method:

```
static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
        {
            List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

            ManagementObjectCollection collection;
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
                collection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (var device in collection)
            {
                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
                ));
            }

            collection.Dispose();
            return devices;
        }
```

What i'm getting in the cameras List is 3 items:

In index 0: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&5E0D3C3&0

In index 1: USB\ROOT_HUB20\4&5E0D3C3&0

In indes 2: USB Root Hub

But what i want to do is first to detect my digital camera connected to the usb.
And then to get the camera name this letters and numbers like 4&5E0D3C3&0 not saying to me a lot.
And last to be able to copy delete files from the camera sd card like a directory like i'm doing it for example on c:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of  `Win32_USBHub` you should use `Win32_USBControllerDevice` and then `Win32_PNPEntity` to get the information about the device itself. See this link 
for an example:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/15/how-can-i-determine-which-usb-devices-are-connected-to-a-computer.aspx